# How can I get this list of translations to print completely?

Tags: python, google-translation-api

Firstly, here is my code:

```
while listIndex < len(dictionary.values()):
        partialDict = dict(list(dictionary.items())[index:listIndex])
        try:
            #setting up the data for the post
            payload = {
                'key': 'blahblahkeyblah',
                'source' : 'en',
                'target' : 'ja',
                'q' : partialDict.values(),
            }
            #translate
            response = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2',data=payload)
            #print response text
            print(response.text + "\n\n")
            #split around translatedText
            testing = response.text.split("translatedText")
            for x in testing:
                search = re.search(':\s\"((\w*)(\s*)?)*', x)
                if(search is not None):
                    test = str(re.search(':\s\"((\w*)(\s*)?)*', x).group(0))[3:]
                    print(test)
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- Send a list of strings to the Google Translate API
- Get back a list of strings
- Save the translated strings into a new dictionary (but for right now I'm just printing the list of translated strings)

What this code actually does is print the first few characters of the translated text. For example, here is a snippet of the response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "入門"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "序章"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "手順"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "このコースには音声があります。一致するテキストを表示するには、[NARRATION] をクリックし、ナレーション ボックスを画面上の読みやすい場所にドラッグします。コースを移動するには、前後の矢印をクリックするか、左上隅をクリックして目次を表示します。"
      },
```

And here is what it will actually print:

```
入門

序章

手順

このコースには音声があります
```

How can I get the fourth line to print completely? As you can see with lines that have very short translations I don't have a problem. but longer translations seem to have an issue. How can I get the translation to show up completely?

Comment: Why are you parsing the response as a string??? Why not loop over the translations? `for translation in response.json()["data"]["translations"]: print(translation["translatedText"])`

Comment: Is the issue that your regex pattern is not correct and you want help fixing it?

Comment: That's just the way my partner did it, so that's what I've got right now. I'm not 100% sure if this is something they talked over with someone and is necessary? it's confusing to me too.

Comment: This happens because the regex matches only part of the text.  If you want to print out the whole text, then why are you using a regex at all?!

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't know, my partner did this and he marked this as "working". but it isn't and I'm not sure how to fix it so that it does.

Comment: He probably marked it as working because they ***still*** didn't encounter a "bad" input. You did. If you want to do the right thing - don't use regex...

Comment: So.... why are you here asking us, instead of asking your partner?

Comment: @JohnGordon I have asked my partner, he says the regex solution will work if we fix it. I have no idea how to fix it, it seems impossible to me so I wanted to ask for help. I don't know how to solve this problem with a regex, and I don't know if it makes sense to, so I though to ask somewhere where people might have more knowledge than me.

Comment: Imagine you had a list, say `l = [1, 2, 3]`. And say I asked you to get the second item of the list. What you think would be a more reasonable way to do it? Option 1) `l[1]` ; or Option 2) parsing the string representation of the list, splitting on the commas, finding the data between the first and the second comma, and possibly converting back to an int? I hope your answer was Option 1 and that you would change the code ***not*** to use regex :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the text manually, read the data as JSON, then loop over the array.

```py
data = response.json()
for o in data['data']['translations']:
    print(o['translatedText'])
```